# How to mesh part of sphere

Tags: mesh

A quite  arbitrarily closed curve `k[φ]`(on the sphere) defines two parts of a sphere. How can I mesh for example the smaller surface part? I intend to use the mesh topology for further calculation (area or something like this)

For example

```
k[φ_] := {Cos[φ] Sin[π/10 - 1/20 π Sin[4 φ]], 
   Sin[φ] Sin[π/10 - 1/20 π Sin[4 φ]], Cos[π/10 - 1/20 π Sin[4 φ]]}
```

defines a surface part [image] which I would like to mesh(triangle)?

My first attempt considering only the boundray

```
ParametricRegion[k[φ], {{φ, 0, 2 Pi}}]
DiscretizeRegion[%] 
(* DiscretizeRegion did not find any sample points *)
```

fails.

Is there an easy way to create such a surface mesh? Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The curve is smooth, and the great circles tangent to the curve never pass through the interior point `{0, 0, 1}` over `φ`:
[image]

Hence the interior can be parametrized by

```
expr = Normalize[k[φ] r + (1 - r) {0, 0, 1}] /. Abs -> Identity // FullSimplify;
```

where $0\leq r\leq1$.

I don't understand why `DiscretizeRegion` returns the weird output

```
DiscretizeRegion[ParametricRegion[expr, {{φ, 0, 2 Pi}, {r, 0, 1}}]]
```

[image]

but `DiscretizeGraphics` works:

```
DiscretizeGraphics[ParametricPlot3D[expr, {φ, 0, 2 Pi}, {r, 0, 1}, PlotPoints -> 65, Mesh -> None]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, very clear answer!